# How to calculate weighted average by group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset:

```
type1   gr1   type2      gr2    val
 a      a1      b        b1     0.6
 a      a1      b        b2     0.8
 a      a2      b        b1     0.6
 a      a2      b        b2     0.2
 a      a3      b        b1     0.1
 a      a3      b        b1     0.5
```

if i calculate mean of val grouped by type1 and type2 `df.groupby(["type1","type2"])["val"].mean().reset_index()`  i will get 0.5 (mean):

```
type1  type2     val
a       b        0.5
```

but how could i get weighted average which is equal `1.5*1/6 + 1.5*1/6 + 0.8*1/6 + 0.4*1/6 +0.3*1/6 = 0.75` . How could i do that with groupby?

Comment: given your sample data, where do you get these values from? `1.5*1/6 + 1.5*1/6 + 0.8*1/6 + 0.4*1/6 +0.3*1/6 = 0.75`

Comment: @lemon it’s a calculation of weighted average. maybe i made a mistake in calculations, but the idea is weighted average